# How to debug intermittent black screens on LG Ultrafine 5K connected via CalDigit TS3+ to a Thunderbolt 4 laptop

Tags: linux, display, thunderbolt, lg-monitor

I have a first-generation LG Ultrafine 5K (27MD5KA-B) display that I'm trying to use with a Panasonic laptop (CF-SV2MFNCR) running Linux. The display requires a Thunderbolt 3 connection, and the laptop is Thunderbolt 4 certified so it should work. When I connect the display directly to the laptop, it doesn't light up at all (the display is completely devoid of any status indicator). However, when I connect the display to a CalDigit TS3 Plus dock, and then connect the dock to the laptop, the display lights up, but I'm experiencing intermittent black screens. The display goes completely dark for less than a second and then light back up again. I've tested the display with a 2019 MacBook Pro, and it works perfectly when connected directly, but also experiences the same intermittent black screens when connected through the CalDigit dock.

I have checked `dmesg` output for error messages when the display goes dark, but there are none. Other than the intermittent black screens, the display works perfectly fine. I've also updated the firmware of the display but that did not bring any change to the situation. I'm wondering what could be causing this issue and if there are any possible fixes.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is the power circuit of the house.

I experienced similar behavior some years back with a new HDMI screen. After long troubleshooting I managed to pinpoint the root cause: my fridge.

It was on the same power circuit with the screen, and every time its compressor switched on or off it caused a fluctuation in the power circuit. As a result the screen switched off and immediately back on when the power stabilized.

The issue resolved itself as soon as I moved my computer equipment to a different outlet.

Comment: That's an interesting story, thanks for sharing that. But the display works just fine when being connected to a MacBook Pro directly, I suspect it's not caused by the power supply.